# Databricks decimal data type column value converted to null

Tags: azure, pyspark, decimal, databricks

I have a column in a delta table with decimal data type of precision 22 and scale 16.

I realized data in this column is being stored as null. For example, the below returns NULL-

```
%python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
spark.range(1).withColumn("new",F.lit('20161125').cast("decimal(22,16)")).display()
```

There exist 100s of delta tables with thousands of columns overall with decimal(22,16) data type.

I tried by setting "allowPrecisionLoss" to true but it did not help.

What could be an elegant solution here, appreciate any thoughts...

Answer (score 0):

With `DECIMAL(22,16)` as per [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/data-types/decimal-type.html):

- `22` is maximum precision (p) - total number of digits that can be stored
- `16` is scale (s) - number of digits to the right of the decimal point

That leaves `22 - 16 = 6` digits to the left of the decimal point.

```
Number: xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx
        ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^
          p-s        s
```

Your number has 8 digits before decimal and doesn't fit in the type.

Either of these would work:

```
F.lit('20161125').cast("decimal(24,16)")
F.lit('20161125').cast("decimal(22,14)")
```